# How to get Tensorflow seq2seq embedding output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to train a sequence to sequence model using tensorflow and have been looking at their example code.

I want to be able to access the vector embeddings created by the encoder as they seem to have some interesting properties.

However, it really isn't clear to me how this can be.

In the vector representations of words example they talk a lot about what these embeddings can be used for and then don't appear to provide a simple way of accessing them, unless I am mistaken.

Any help figuring out how to access them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

As with all Tensorflow operations, most variables are dynamically created. There are different ways to access these variables ( and their values ). Here, the variable you are interested in is part of the set of trained variables. To access these, we can thus use the `tf.trainable_variables()` function:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    print var.name
```

which will give us - for a GRU seq2seq model, the following list:

```
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/embedding:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/OutputProjectionWrapper/Linear/Matrix:0
embedding_rnn_seq2seq/embedding_rnn_decoder/rnn_decoder/OutputProjectionWrapper/Linear/Bias:0
```

This tells us that the embedding is called `embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0`, which we can then use to retrieve a pointer to that variable in our earlier iterator:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    print var.name
    if var.name == 'embedding_rnn_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0':
        embedding_op = var
```

This we can then pass along with other ops to our session-run:

```
_, loss_t, summary, embedding = sess.run([train_op, loss, summary_op, embedding_op], feed_dict)
```

and we have ourselves the (batch-list of) embeddings ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143046/tensorflow-seq2seq-get-sequence-hidden-state), but it is based on tensorflow-0.6 which is quite out of date. So I update his answer in tensorflow-0.8 which is also similar to that in the newest version.

(*represent where to modify)

```
losses = []
outputs = []
*states = []
with ops.op_scope(all_inputs, name, "model_with_buckets"):
    for j, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
        with variable_scope.variable_scope(variable_scope.get_variable_scope(),
                                                                             reuse=True if j > 0 else None):
            *bucket_outputs, _ ,bucket_states= seq2seq(encoder_inputs[:bucket[0]],
                                                                    decoder_inputs[:bucket[1]])
            outputs.append(bucket_outputs)
            if per_example_loss:
                losses.append(sequence_loss_by_example(
                        outputs[-1], targets[:bucket[1]], weights[:bucket[1]],
                        softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))
            else:
                losses.append(sequence_loss(
                    outputs[-1], targets[:bucket[1]], weights[:bucket[1]],
                    softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function))

return outputs, losses, *states
```

at python/ops/seq2seq, modify embedding_attention_seq2seq()

```
if isinstance(feed_previous, bool):
    *outputs, states = embedding_attention_decoder(
                decoder_inputs, encoder_state, attention_states, cell,
                num_decoder_symbols, embedding_size, num_heads=num_heads,
                output_size=output_size, output_projection=output_projection,
                feed_previous=feed_previous,
                initial_state_attention=initial_state_attention)
    *return outputs, states, encoder_state

    # If feed_previous is a Tensor, we construct 2 graphs and use cond.
def decoder(feed_previous_bool):
    reuse = None if feed_previous_bool else True
    with variable_scope.variable_scope(variable_scope.get_variable_scope(),reuse=reuse):
        outputs, state = embedding_attention_decoder(
                decoder_inputs, encoder_state, attention_states, cell,
                num_decoder_symbols, embedding_size, num_heads=num_heads,
                output_size=output_size, output_projection=output_projection,
                feed_previous=feed_previous_bool,
                update_embedding_for_previous=False,
                initial_state_attention=initial_state_attention)
        return outputs + [state]

    outputs_and_state = control_flow_ops.cond(feed_previous, lambda: decoder(True), lambda: decoder(False))                                                                                                                                                           
    *return outputs_and_state[:-1], outputs_and_state[-1], encoder_state
```

at model/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py modify init()

```
if forward_only:
    *self.outputs, self.losses, self.states= tf.nn.seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
            self.encoder_inputs, self.decoder_inputs, targets,
            self.target_weights, buckets, lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, True),
            softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
    # If we use output projection, we need to project outputs for decoding.
    if output_projection is not None:
        for b in xrange(len(buckets)):
            self.outputs[b] = [
                    tf.matmul(output, output_projection[0]) + output_projection[1]
                    for output in self.outputs[b]
            ]
else:
    *self.outputs, self.losses, _ = tf.nn.seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
            self.encoder_inputs, self.decoder_inputs, targets,
            self.target_weights, buckets,
            lambda x, y: seq2seq_f(x, y, False),
            softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_function)
```

at model/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py modify step()

```
if not forward_only:
    return outputs[1], outputs[2], None    # Gradient norm, loss, no outputs.
else:
    *return None, outputs[0], outputs[1:], outputs[-1]    # No gradient norm, loss, outputs.
```

with all these done, we can get the encoded states by calling :

```
_, _, output_logits, states = model.step(sess, encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs,
                                                                     target_weights, bucket_id, True)
print (states)
```

in the translate.py.